# Assigning a custom variable to real_ip_header

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, request-headers

I am trying to get the client IP when the requests are either coming through an application load balancer, or through AWS Cloudfront.

When its just coming through load balancer, I use `X-Forwarded-For` header (set by load balancer) and if its coming through the CloudFront, I use the custom header `CloudFront-Viewer-Address` set by Cloudfront.

Since the application is not aware if its coming through  Cloudfront or ALB, I need to make the distinction, which I do it with a `map`:

```
map $http_CloudFront_Viewer_Address $remote_addr_header {
  "~*"     $http_CloudFront_Viewer_Address;
  default  $http_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

This map is working. I can log `$remote_addr_header` and it is getting the correct value.

However, this is not working:

```
real_ip_header $remote_addr_header;
```

Although the following are working:

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

```
real_ip_header CloudFront-Viewer-Address;
```

So I am wondering if I am not able to directly assign a variable to `real_ip_header`, as the documentation says
*Syntax:    real_ip_header field | X-Real-IP | X-Forwarded-For | proxy_protocol;
Default:

real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
Context:    http, server, location*

Is there a way I can use the custom variable `$remote_addr_header` in  `real_ip_header`?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am searching for cloudfront forwared header permission that exclude to add all ranges already over view years

Answer (score 2):

As the name implies and [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) explicitly states (emphasis is mine):

The `ngx_http_realip_module module` is used to change the client address and optional port to those sent in the **specified header field**.

The directive interprets its argument as the name of a HTTP header where the IP address should be taken from - it is not being interpreted as an **immediate constant** as you may hope.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did because there is two paths for my requests:

```
    map $http_cf_connecting_ip $remote_addr_header_cf {
        ~*     $http_cf_connecting_ip;
        default  $http_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    map $http_CloudFront_Viewer_Address $remote_addr_header {
        # Use a regex to filter out the port
        "~*^(?<cf_viewer_address>.*):\d{5}$" $cf_viewer_address;

        default $remote_addr_header_cf;
    }
```

This works for the following config

```
CloudFront ────────► CloudFlare ─────► Nginx
      ▲                 ▲
      │                 │
     User ──────────────┘
```